# How to display dynamic pages correcly in expressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, loops, express

My app.js file has the following array of objects:

```
var people = [
        {name: "Henrique Melo", username: "heenrique", email: "henrique.example@hotmail.com"},
        {name: "João Pessoa", username: "jooao", email: "joao.example@hotmail.com"}
    ];
```

I'm trying to create a page for each person with the following code:

```
app.get("/:username", function(req, res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
       if (people[i].username === req.params.username) {
            res.render("description.ejs", { pageTitle : "Profile", user : people[i] });
        } else {
            res.status(404).json("User not found.");
        }
    }
});
```

The description page for the first person in the array ("/heenrique") loads perfectly, but any following object will not be displayed. When I type ("/jooao" - the username of the 2nd person in the array) I get the "user not found" message in my else statement. There must be a problem with the loop I created. Please, shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the loop has to continue for the next item without rendering any error (Error occurs on 1st iteration when people[0] don't match the requested username). A working approach would be like this.

```
app.get("/:username", function(req, res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
       if (people[i].username === req.params.username) {
            res.render("description.ejs", { pageTitle : "Profile", user : people[i] });
            return;
        }
    }
    res.status(404).json("User not found.");
});
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! What is the role "return" is playing? Also, how is it possible that res.status(404).json("User not found.") doesn't get executed for every GET request to "/:username"?

Comment: "return" stops execution and exits the function immediately, with no further execution. It simplifies the code and improves its readability.